# Animate jQuery effect

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, animation, effects

I want to design a effect for a div such the effect from this site(from the live comments box, on the right side).

I am using animate effect. 
Something like:

```
jQuery(".aux_content").animate({"width":400+"px"},1000);
jQuery(".aux_content").animate({"height":500+"px"},{duration:1000, queue: true});
jQuery("#scrollingDiv").animate({"height":500+"px"},{duration:1000, queue: true});
```

It doesn't show how it should. Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(".aux_content").animate({width:"400px",height:"500px"},1000);
```

Try that instead, keep the number inside the quotes.  But the problem is you aren't telling or showing how they ought to look and how they currently are, so it is hard to say completely what you need.

Also, you need to keep the names outside of quotes.

```
$(".aux_content").animate({width:"400px"},1000, function() {
    $(".aux_content").animate({height:"500px"},1000, function() {
         $("#scrollingDiv").animate({height:"500px"},1000);
    });
});
```

EDIT:  Also, forgot to mention, you can animate more than just one property in the animate string.  Showed you how to do it above.

Comment: That will make no difference - `400+"px"` results in a string just as you have used, so it's basically the same thing: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/XRkS8/

Comment: I really don't know what the person wants, but my guess is that it is a problem with syntax.  I just discovered they also were storing the label in a quote, which doesn't appear to be how to do it according to documentation and how I have implemented it before.  I edited the answer to be more thorough.

Comment: this thing makes the width and the height both in the same time. This should happen once at a time

Comment: Okay so then you want to do it only after it is complete, and before it would just do it once it is done, right?  Updating to show you how you can manage that.